# How to update EnvironmentObject variable from Coordinator class?

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, swiftui, coordinator-pattern

I'm using Coordinator (conforms to LoginButtonDelegate) object to receive user data (profile, name) when user completes authorisation via FB Login Button. 
Coordinator().userId property is updated with user ID but i need to pass it 1 level up to the LoginView and to update EnvironmentObject called thisSession (make thisSession.userId = Coordinator().userId somehow).

Is there any way to do that? I tried playing with ObservableObject/Published properties but i can't update parent object's properties from Coordinator.

Another idea is to subscribe to Auth.auth() changes but it seems too complicated and a bit "old school" solution. There show be some easy way i am missing.

Any hints/ideas?

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var thisSession: CurrentSession
    @ObservedObject var mainData = MainViewModel()

    var facebookView = facebook()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            facebookView.frame(width: 240, height: 50)
            Text("\(self.thisSession.userId ?? "none")")
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView().environmentObject(CurrentSession())
    }
}


struct facebook: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var thisSession: CurrentSession
    @ObservedObject var coordinator = Coordinator()

    func makeCoordinator() -> facebook.Coordinator {
        return self.coordinator
        //facebook.Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<facebook>) -> FBLoginButton {

        let button = FBLoginButton()
        button.delegate = self.coordinator
        print("UPDATED")

        return button
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<facebook>) {
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate, ObservableObject {
        @Published var userId: String?
        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {

            if error != nil{

                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            if AccessToken.current != nil{

                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)

                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res,er) in

                    if er != nil{
                        print((er?.localizedDescription)!)
                        return

                    }
                    print("email: \(String(describing: res?.user.email))")
                    print("name: \(String(describing: res?.user.displayName))")
                    self.userId = String(describing: res?.user.displayName)
                }
            }
        }

        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            print("logged out")
            try! Auth.auth().signOut()

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, as coordinator is created during update the environment object should be already injected and present, so it should work

```
struct facebook: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var thisSession: CurrentSession

    func makeCoordinator() -> facebook.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(session: thisSession)              // << here !!
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<facebook>) -> FBLoginButton {

        let button = FBLoginButton()
        button.delegate = self.coordinator
        print("UPDATED")

        return button
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<facebook>) {
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate, ObservableObject {
        let session: CurrentSession
        init(session: CurrentSession) {
            self.session = session
        }

        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {

            if error != nil{

                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            if AccessToken.current != nil{

                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)

                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res,er) in

                    if er != nil{
                        print((er?.localizedDescription)!)
                        return

                    }
                    print("email: \(String(describing: res?.user.email))")
                    print("name: \(String(describing: res?.user.displayName))")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {   // << here 
                        self.session.userId = String(describing: res?.user.displayName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            print("logged out")
            try! Auth.auth().signOut()

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if you got me right. I wanna update _environment object_ with the data FROM Coordinator.

Comment: @eugene_prg, EnvironmentObject is just an observer wrapper around reference to ObservableObject, so in proposed solution this reference is passed into coordinator where as intended it is changed.

Comment: How does it happen that coordinator has access to the reference of EnvironmentObject ? We even does not pass the reference when coordinator is created, we pass the VALUE. So how does it update it?